# Maintaining exact geometries with st_subdivide of PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry

I have noticed that when I use st_subdivide() function in PostGIS, the resulting area of the polygons can be different than the input.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this happening?

Comment: Could you share some source geometry as test data?

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use the subdivided geometries for analysis.

Comment: @IanTurton -- Yeah, I am starting to think that also.I'm trying to do an intersection between a Canada provinces shapefile, and a Canada postcodes shapefile. One of the rows has a polygon which is 1.28m points. After 10 hours it still had not finished.So I thought sub-divide would help, but it doesn't seem to as it changes the shapes of the polygons a bit.

Comment: What kind of difference are you getting (a few cm2 or thousands of km2)? How do you measure it? (let's not forget the obvious, that a single postal code could cover multiple subdivided polygons of the same province... and could even slightly cover multiple provinces) Make sure the original geometries are valid, as well as the subdivided ones.